# Signing in with geckodriver gives Invalid CSRF Tokens error

Tags: java, selenium, csrf, geckodriver

I'm using jUnit, geckodriver and Seleninum to perform a series of tests on the Scientic American website, for learning purposes.

These are the respective versions:
- jUnit 4.12;
- Selenium Java 3.4.0;
- geckodriver 0.17.0 win64;
- Firefox 54.0 win64.

I'm having trouble testing the signing in form. After a run the test below, the login is unsuccessful and ends up on a page with the message "Login: Invalid CSRF Tokens".

Everything works fine if I sign in by hand.

This is my test class:

```
public class SeleniumTest {
    private static WebDriver driver;
    private WebElement element;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void openBrowser() {
        String url = "https://www.scientificamerican.com/";     
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");       
        DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        dc.setCapability("marionette", true);
        driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(url);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSignIn() {
        driver.findElement(By.id("signin-click")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.className("signin-flyout__form__submit"))));

        element = driver.findElement(By.id("emailAddress1"));
        element.click();
        element.clear();
        element.sendKeys("testmail@dispostable.com");

        element = driver.findElement(By.id("password1"));
        element.click();
        element.clear();
        element.sendKeys("123123123");

        driver.findElement(By.className("signin-flyout__form__submit")).click();            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("account-tooltip__title")));
        element = driver.findElement(By.className("account-tooltip__title"));
    }
}
```

And this is the code of the signing in form:

```
<form class="signin-flyout__form" action="https://www.scientificamerican.com/my-account/login/?s=1" method="post">
    <input name="slatAction" value="public:account.login" type="hidden">
    <input name="flyoutlogin" value="true" type="hidden">
    <input name="csrf_token" value="EF076BBB82FB3698878C9DCA0DBA5B1B" type="hidden">
    <input name="csrf_token_expires" value="170620234403162" type="hidden">
    <label class="signin-flyout__form__label" for="emailAddress1">Email:</label>
    <input id="emailAddress1" class="signin-flyout__form__input" name="emailAddress" data-signin-email="" type="textbox">
    <label class="signin-flyout__form__label" for="password1">Password:</label>
    <input id="password1" class="signin-flyout__form__input" name="password" data-signin-password="" type="password">
    <a class="signin-flyout__form__forgot" href="https://www.scientificamerican.com/my-account/forgot-password/">Forgot password?</a>
    <button class="btn btn--small btn--inverted signin-flyout__form__submit" type="submit" data-signin-submit-btn="">Login</button>
    <img class="signin-flyout__form__loading" src="/public/resources/loader-824962d9e67c8497c9ef428a9fdfad71.gif" alt="Loading" data-signin-loading="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Try the following code. That worked for me

```
driver.findElement(By.id("emailAddress1")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("emailAddress1")).sendKeys("testmail@dispostable.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password1")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("password1")).sendKeys("123123123");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.className("signin-flyout__form__submit")).click();
```